# Replace html encoding with url encoding

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, urlencode, html-encode

We are getting random hits like:

`/abc?p=2&amp;utm_campaign=xyz-campaign&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_source=newsletter`

Notice `&amp;` which is html encoding for &. I have checked the possible sources but they all contain '&' only. 
I want replace all `&amp;` with &. Is there a way to achieve it? I have removed complete string as of now using below given rule. But this is not right!

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (&amp;)
    RewriteRule (.*?) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the referer in your logs so you can find the source of the problem and (also) fix it there.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S++\s++([^\s?]*+\?\S*?&)amp;(\S*+)
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [DPI,L,R=301]
```

That will do one redirect per ampersand without messing about decoding and re-encoding the URL. Less efficient but more reliable.

Comment: Thanks Walf It shall solve our problem. The count is 74 out of 1 million for yesterday, but customer experience matters!